# Rails: Rake task parsing with Nokogiri inserts: --- !ruby/object:Nokogiri::XML::Element {} into DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, rake, nokogiri

Having trouble setting up a Rake Task. Here is the code:

```
    task :fetch_games => :environment do

require 'nokogiri'

require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))

  games = doc.xpath('//game')

    games.each do |game|
      @data = Game.new(
        :name            => game.at('name').text,
        :publisher       => game.at('publisher').text,)



    @data.save

    if @data.save
        puts "Success"
    else
        puts "Didn't work"
    end
    end
end
```

It runs without error but in the database the entries show: "--- !ruby/object:Nokogiri::XML::Element {}
"

Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself the xpath syntax was incorrect. I need to use:

```
/game
```

instead of

```
//game
```